# Android onActivityResult not working

Tags: android, android-activity

Im not sure why my code isn't calling `onActivityResult` when i finish the started Activity.

Here is the calling class:

```
public class RecognitionActivity extends Activity {

static final int NEW_PICTURE_REQUEST = 1;
static final int RECOGNISE_TEXT_REQUEST = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recognition);

    startCamera();
}

private void startCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, NEW_PICTURE_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(this, requestCode + ":" + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Here is the ***CameraActivity*** Class, or at least the relevent parts:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

private Camera camera;
private CameraPreview cameraPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    camera = Camera.open();
    cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);

    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(cameraPreview);

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

The strange thing is, when the `cameraActivity` activity finishes, so does the calling activity (`RecognitionActivity`) Im not seeing the `Toast` pop up from `onActivityResult` either?

EDIT: Here is the RecognitionActivity Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".RecognitionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recognition"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
```

EDIT2: Ignore this, i figured it out, i derped. Was opening cameraActivity from my launcher instead of recognitionActivity. Old testing code. Damnit.

Comment: post your manifest entry of RecognitionActivity

Comment: Suggestion: add logging, like `Log.d("~~~","onActivityResult")`, and see if the message appears in the `adb logcat` output. Probably it's a toast problem.

Comment: you must debug with breakpoints then...no issue with filters...

Comment: Nothing is being output into logcat from what i can see.

Comment: screenOrientation of CameraActivity??

Comment: breakpoints arent catching within onActivityResult either :/

Comment: What would screenOrientation be doing?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html seems intent filter plays a pert. Hope this helps.

Comment: @DylanLundy keep `@Override` on your `onActivityResult` method and then check. hope that will work.

Comment: isn't @Override just a documentation thing? either way it didn't work :(

Comment: nopes need to use that. @DylanLundy

Comment: @DylanLundy try to change  `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);` to `setResult(RESULT_OK);` And also add `@Override`  on your `onActivityResult`.And don't forget to clear your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 On button click we can start the camera intent  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
    and fetch the image path using content resolver.

        @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&  data!=null) {
                if (requestCode == ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    picturepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();


                }

                else    if (requestCode == ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY) 
                {
                     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                         picturepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your intent needs something like this,

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, NEW_PICTURE_REQUEST);
```

this may help you out.. http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Answer (score 0):

try to comment the following areas in CameraActivity ...

```
private Camera camera;
private CameraPreview cameraPreview;

camera = Camera.open();
cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);

FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(cameraPreview);
```

then run the project...i think that gonna work... mine is working too...
so,the problem is in your Camera logic...you have to improve your code, refer @shristi